# Access static file in code igniter sitemap.xml

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have no idea about Codeigniter 3. I am trying to access the sitemap.xml file. Can someone help me out?

I have tried to access using a .htaccess file and also try using the controller and routes as well. It using a .htaccess file I am getting a 404 error and Using MVC it is generating only a particular section urls.